# Ubuntu wouldn't run Cisco packettracer

Tags: ubuntu

I installed Cisco on Ubuntu 19.**0**4 and then entered

`# sudo packettracer start`

and got `starting packettracer 7.1`  on screen, but nothing seemed to happen after that.

Comment: Check logs, e.g does `dmesg | less `  (hit `>`  to get to the end) tell anything related?

Comment: ... and please tell WHERE, in which format (apt, deb, tgz, ...) you got it and HOW you installed "Cisco".